# How to distribute the initial input files to nodes in Hadoop MapReduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a hadoop cluster with two computers, One as a master and another one as a slave. My input data is present on the Local disk of Master and I have also copied the input data files in the HDFS system. Now my question is, if I run the MapReduce task on this cluster then the whole input file is present on only one system [ which i think is opposed to the MapReduce's basic principle of "Data Locality" ]. I would like to know if there is any mechanism to distribute/partition the initial files so that the input files can be distributed on the different nodes of the cluster.

Comment: Why would you need to worry about this with 2 computers? And why should you worry about this at all, let Hadoop handle the replication of the data.

Comment: If you're replication factor is greater than 2, your file actually exists entirely on both machines.

Comment: @climbage but one of his nodes is master node, so it won't be running a datanode

Comment: @Chaos You can run a datanode and namenode on the same machine

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your cluster is composed of Node 1 and Node 2. If Node 1 is master, then there is no Datanode running on that node. So you have only a Datanode on Node 2, so I'm not sure what you mean when you say `"so that the input files can be distributed on the different nodes of the cluster"` because with your current setup, you just have 1 node on which data can be stored.

But if you consider a generic n node cluster, then if you copy data into HDFS, then data is distributed onto different nodes of the cluster by hadoop itself, so you wouldn't have to worry about that.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. The thing which is confusing me is if there are n nodes and hadoop performs the data replication doesn't it uses the network bandwidth [ to  perform the data replication ]. Is this good performance wise?

Comment: it will definitely use network bandwidth whenever you put a file on HDFS, even without replication, but that is part and parcel of a distributed system. Now when you say "Is this good performance wise", assuming you mean speed of writing files, yes, it will be slower than writing it on a single node with no distribution, but again Hadoop is designed for write-once read-many kind of data, so it's not so important to have good performance on file writes.